# Simulating windows laptop in virtual machine?

Tags: windows, virtualization

I wonder if there is a way to simulate laptop in a virtual machine. Specifically, I would like to simulate the lid closing behavior. I checked virtual box and it doesn't seem to have this kind of feature.

Thanks!

Comment: The end user can always choose what to do when the lid is closed.The options are "Hybernate", "Power off" or "sleep". What difference does it make?

Comment: @Shoban, while the end user can choose, applications still get notified and can take custom actions regardless of what the computer is about to do.

Comment: Exactly.. So my question is is there a need for simulating "Lid Close"? ;-)

Comment: @Shoban, sure, if you write your own code that responds to this event and want to test it in a virtualized environment, then yes, there is a need to simulate it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write an application to do that.

The message you are interested in broadcasting is [WM_POWERBROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Take a [look here](http://www.gamedeception.net/threads/13358-Catch-windows-event-%28laptop-lid%29) if you also need to catch it.