# Simulate battery saver mode by broadcasting WM_POWERBROADCAST

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to simulate the "battery saver" functionality of a laptop but I do not have a laptop to test on. I've attempted to broadcast a `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message with the corresponding GUID to simulate the "battery saver" mode but the message was never received by my app.

Is there a way to further debug whether the message was sent properly?

```
    POWERBROADCAST_SETTING pps = { GUID_POWER_SAVING_STATUS , 1, 1 };
    DWORD recepients = BSM_APPLICATIONS;
    long result = BroadcastSystemMessage(BSF_POSTMESSAGE, &recepients, WM_POWERBROADCAST, PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE, (LPARAM)&pps);
```

Relevant question: [Simulating windows laptop in virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486560/simulating-windows-laptop-in-virtual-machine)

Comment: You can't use `PostMessage` to send pointers, since `PostMessage` is asynchronous and the data being pointed at could go away before the message is processed. Try using `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST)` instead.  Or, if you are just testing how your own app responds to battery events, just send `WM_POWERBROADCAST` directly to your window and don't broadcast it at all

Comment: `SendMessage` Worked!